# What is the correct way to update Jupyter Notebook extensions?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

What is the correct way to upgrade Jupyter Notebook extensions (e.g. RISE, ipywidgets)? I have a routine which keeps my Python packages updated by running `pip install --upgrade`, and this downloads and installs new Notebook extension versions too, when they are available.

Should I also run `jupyter nbextension install --py --sys-prefix`, and possibly even `jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix` for each of the Notebook extensions which pip gets a new package?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jupyter nbextension install --py --sys-prefix` installs the extension code in the correct place, so yes you should run this when you update an extension.

`jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix` just writes in a JSON file to load the relevant extension - so unless the extension changes its name then no, you don't need to rerun this.

Answer (score 3):

Consider running `jupyter labextension update --all` in terminal to check and install updates.

Comment: 2023: (Deprecated) Updating extensions with the jupyter labextension update command is now deprecated and will be removed in future versions. Users should manage prebuilt extensions with package managers like pip and conda…

Answer (score 1):

if you've installed using anaconda you could open an anaconda prompt and write

```
conda update rise
```

for example. that seems to work for me.